# Fixed point continous function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:R\to R$ be a continous function, without fixed points,and $n,m$ positive integers. Let $f^k$ denote $f$ composed with itself $k$ times.Show that the system: $f^m(x)=y$ and $f^n(y)=x$ has no solutions.

Let's assume there exist $x,y$ that satisfy that system.
By composition we get $f^{m+n}(x)=x$ and $f^{m+n}(y)=y$. And so the problem I wrote before it's basically this one.

Comment: What "result" are you referring to? It looks like a standard exercise. Is that your homework? What are your thoughts? It says "Show that". You think you can show the contrary?

Comment: I reduced an exercise to proving this but I can't do it. Bad wording, sorry.

Comment: @uniquesolution It's an olympiad problem I'm working on. Should I post the original problem? I didn't know how to write an equation system which was in the initial statement of the problem.

Comment: Please don't make drastic changes to the question after someone has answered it. It wastes everyone's time.

Comment: It is the same question.

Comment: It is not. ${}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ has no fixed point. Then the graph of $f$ cannot touch the line $\{(x,x)\}_x$.

Assume $f(t) >t$ for all $t$.

Then $x = f^k(x) > f^{k-1}(t) > \cdots > f(x)$, which is a contradiction.

Similarly if we assume $f(t) <t $ for all $t$.